# Hibernate Fetching large number of records

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project which needs to `fetch a large number of records`, as I know that `hibernate` is limiting the session cache. I am also aware about the basic pagination.

Is there a more elegant solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Large number of data !! Depends on the type of data being retrieved.

**Scenario 1:**

Data being retrieved from a single table means single domain class.
i.e. Only a table having no foreign key relationships with any of the other table.

In this case,

either `limit` the data retrieved by the query or pagination.

**Scenario 2:**

Data is related to many classes or table, having foreign key relations.

Use something like this --> `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`
`Annotation` depends on the type of relation that you have.
i.e., OneToMany, ManyToOne...

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand Scenario1. But in Scenario2 let's assume that one parent record is having thousand child records and i need to some processing on all the child records. i will be reading all the records and this way session cache may get exhausted and OutOfMemory Issue may come. How to handle this situation??